# Enable/Disable USB-Port

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, usb

I have to disable a specific USB-port with a program or a .bat or a .vbs file.

This program would have to check if the port is enabled, disable this, and if is disabled, enable it.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [`devcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544746%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#ddk_example_30_disable_devices_by_an_id_pattern_tools). Note that if you're using Windows 7 you must use the version included with the [Windows Driver Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11800). Earlier versions will not work correctly on Windows 7.